# Java simple callback

Tags: java, methods, callback

It is basic problem. I have class A which gives some task to class B. When class B finish the tast it must notify class A. I want register A class method as callback in class B.

I really want do it in this way, not by observer pattern with interface Observable.

```
public class A
{
    public void A()
    { 
        B b = new B()
        b.registerCallback(callback);
    }

    private void callback()
    {

    }

}

public class B
{
    private ???? callbackoNotify;

    public class registerCallback(??? callback)
    {
        callbackoNotify = callback;
    }

    public void notify()
    { 
        callback();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define an `interface` for the callback.

```
interface Callback{
    void call();
}
```

Then, let class A implement it.

```
class A implements Callback{
    private B b;

    public A(){
        b = new B();
        b.registerCallback(this);
    }    

    // Implementation of the callback interface
    public void call(){

    }
}
```

Then, let class B to handle the callback.

```
public class B
{
    private Callback callbackoNotify;

    public class registerCallback(Callback callback)
    {
        callbackoNotify = callback;
    }

    public void notify()
    { 
        callbackNotify.call();
    }
}
```

But in the above scenario, `callbackNotify` can be **null**. Therefore, it is better if you can pass that callback in the constructor to B.

Hope you got the idea.

Comment: Then class A Has public method 'call' which everyone can call, although only B should can.

Comment: So, make A an abstract class that extends Callback. Make B a concrete class that extends A with a protected method that is "call".

Maybe if you're having these issues in the first place, you should look into an asynchronous framework such as Ratpack.

Comment: @aQuu That is the use of interfaces. In OOP, if we are to call this `call` method, we should have an object of type `Callback`. If you are doing `a.call()` where a is of type `A`, then it is a bad practice. Even in class `B`, we keep the reference to the callback in  the type `Callback`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without callbacks as well.  Here's an example:

```
A a = ...
B b = ...
```

Let's say b has a doTask method like this:

```
public void doTask(Runnable task);
```

A can now call it like this:

```
b.doTask(() -> {System.out.println("Hi There");});
```

However, A will not be informed when the task gets completed.  You could simply change the task like this:

```
Runnable taskForB = () -> {System.out.println("Hi There");};
Runnable wrapperForTaskWithCallback = () -> {
    taskForB.run();
    taskWasFinished();
};
```

And then run the wrapper task instead:

```
b.doTask(wrapperForTaskWithCallback);
```

And give A a method:

```
public void taskWasFinished();
```